# GitLab Pipeline deploy on Kubernetes with agents in multiple cluster

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

i am newbie for gitlab.
I don't understand how to create a pipeline for deploy an immage in different kubernetes cluster with agents.

for example i have :

dev cluster -> agent 1

test cluster -> agent 2

production cluster -> agent 3

now it's possibile in a single pipeline to deploy in every cluster ? how can i tell which agent to use for deploy in a specific environment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will depend on your use case, but on your jobs you can use `kubectl` to specify the context to where you are deploying.

`kubectl config set-context $GITLAB_AGENT_URL:$AGENT_NAME`

where `$GITLAB_AGENT_URL` is the name of the project where the config of your Kubernetes Agents is stored.